Get products by attribute in WooCommerce
I have  products with many attributes. Attribute values can be size,color,... . I am trying to create a custom search but I can't get the query to pull any product.
    $product_attributes = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
    
    $attributes = array();
    foreach ($product_attributes as $attribute) {
        $attribute_name =  $attribute->attribute_name;
        $attribute_value = isset($params[$attribute_name]) ? $params[$attribute_name] : '';
        if (!empty($attribute_value)) {
            $attributes['pa_' .$attribute_name] = $attribute_value;
           
        }
    }
    
    $ordering              = WC()->query->get_catalog_ordering_args();
    $ordering['orderby']   = array_shift(explode(' ', $ordering['orderby']));
    $ordering['orderby']   = stristr($ordering['orderby'], 'price') ? 'meta_value_num' : $ordering['orderby'];
    
    dump($attributes);
    $args = array(
        'status' => 'publish',
        'limit' => -1,
        'return'            => 'ids',
        'stock_status'      => 'instock',
        'visibility'        => 'visible',
        'paginate'          => true,
        'orderby'           => $ordering['orderby'],
        'order'             => 'DESC',

        'attribute' => $attributes,
    );

    $products = wc_get_products($args);

what`s the problem

Thre issue is how the wc_get_products() function is used, the function doesn't directly support searching by attributes in the way you have structured it.
To search for products based on custom attr you need to use tax_query within the args array
Note: woocommerce attr are stored as custom taxonomies like ('pa_size', 'pa_color')
Updated code
$product_attributes = wc_get_attribute_taxonomies();
    
$tax_query = array('relation' => 'AND');

foreach ($product_attributes as $attribute) {
    $attribute_name =  $attribute->attribute_name;
    $attribute_value = isset($params[$attribute_name]) ? $params[$attribute_name] : '';
    if (!empty($attribute_value)) {
        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_' . $attribute_name,
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $attribute_value,
        );
    }
}

$ordering = WC()->query->get_catalog_ordering_args();
$ordering['orderby'] = stristr($ordering['orderby'], 'price') ? 'meta_value_num' : $ordering['orderby'];

$args = array(
    'status' => 'publish',
    'limit' => -1,
    'return' => 'ids',
    'stock_status' => 'instock',
    'visibility' => 'visible',
    'paginate' => true,
    'orderby' => $ordering['orderby'],
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => $tax_query,
);

$products = wc_get_products($args);

// Debug
dump($products);

